# Create Inner Gremlin query using edge information

Tags: graph, titan, gremlin

I'm trying to create user Notification whenever any user comments on user's post.

i'm using following gremlin query -

```
g.v(512).outE('Notification').order{it.b.PostedDate <=> it.a.PostedDate}[0..3].transform{ [notificationInfo:it,postInfo:it.inV]}
```

and am getting following result -

[image]

Am getting NotificationInitiatedByVertexId value in edge. how can I use that vertex id (ie. NotificationInitiatedByVertexId: 1280) to get information about the vertex in the same query result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest trying to add it to the transform statement you already have:

```
g.v(512).outE('Notification').order{it.b.PostedDate <=> it.a.PostedDate}[0..3].transform{ [notificationInfo:it,postInfo:it.inV,notifiedV:g.v(it.NotificationInitiatedByVertexId)]}
```

Comment: How can I group notification with same postInfo._id ?